# Почему так работает протокол Comparable?

Tags: swift4, protocol, compare

новичок, штудирую протоколы. Есть такой код:

```
class Workout: CustomStringConvertible, Equatable, Comparable {

    var distance: Double
    var time: Double
    var identifier: Int       


    init(distance: Double, time: Double, identifier: Int) {
        self.distance = distance
        self.time = time
        self.identifier = identifier
    }

    var description: String {
        return "This workout has following results: distance - \(distance),       time - \(time), identifier - \(identifier)"
    }

    static func == (lhs: Workout, rhs: Workout) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
    }

    static func < (lhs: Workout, rhs: Workout) -> Bool {
        return lhs.identifier < rhs.identifier
    }

}

let workout1 = Workout(distance: 30.5, time: 35.6, identifier: 1)
let workout2 = Workout(distance: 55.88, time: 45.33, identifier: 2)
let workout3 = Workout(distance: 100.80, time: 1.30, identifier: 3)
let workout4 = Workout(distance: 56.10, time: 50.3, identifier: 4)
let workout5 = Workout(distance: 250.30, time: 90.50, identifier: 5)

var workouts: [Workout] = [workout1, workout2, workout3, workout4, workout5]

var sortedWorkouts = workouts.sorted(by: >)

print(sortedWorkouts)
```

Печатает:

```
[This workout has following results: distance - 250.3, time - 90.5, identifier - 5, This workout has following results: distance - 56.1, time - 50.3, identifier - 4, This workout has following results: distance - 100.8, time - 1.3, identifier - 3, This workout has following results: distance - 55.88, time - 45.33, identifier - 2, This workout has following results: distance - 30.5, time - 35.6, identifier - 1]
```

Вопрос такой - при реализации протокола внутри класса я указываю оператор "меньше чем" ( < ), а когда уже сортирую массив, в параметре метода sorted указываю оператор "больше чем" ( > ).

И оно все равно работает, массив сортируется от большего к меньшему. Но ведь по логике должно быть так как заявлено в протоколе, т.е. от меньшего к большему.

Т.е. в одном месте оператор - <, а в другом - >, и оно все равно правильно работает? Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, что Вы указали, так и отсортировало. Если Вы укажете:

```
var sortedWorkouts = workouts.sorted(by: <)
```

то отсортировано будет по возрастанию.

Comparable содержит 5 функций, которые можно реализовать, но обязательных 2. Остальные 3 (если они не реализованы) выводятся на основе обязательных. Т.е. Вы задали правило для `<`, соответственно `>` по умолчанию будет равно неудовлетворению правила для `<`: если не меньше, значит оно больше.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! А какие две функции обязательные?

Comment: @maxMas которые у Вас реализованы: `<` и `==`